# За O(1) пересчитывать количество инверсий при циклическом сдвиге влево

Tags: c++, алгоритм, структуры-данных, олимпиада, сортировка-слиянием

Есть перестановка, а также q запрос: найти количество инверсий в циклическом сдвиге этой перестановки на A элементов влево. Есть только одна проблема, размер перестановки 3⋅10^5. Просто найти количество инверсий у меня получается за n⋅log(n), но как отвечать на запрос при сдвиге я не знаю. Если у вас какие-либо идеи, пожалуйста, пишите, буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: Дайте ссылку на проверяющую систему.

Comment: Это задача C с ИОИП 2021 и она немного о другом, просто я свёл её к этому https://rsr-olymp.ru/upload/files/tasks/4337/2020/18474243-tasks-iikt-7-11-final-20-21.pdf

Comment: Вы несколько неудачно упростили задачу. Для инверсии в отдельном разряде есть всего десять значений. Подсчёт инверсий для десятизначного алфавита проще чем для перестановки (алфавит размера *N*). Ответ MBo вам пригодится. Для шести разрядов вычислите шесть массивов "взаимных инверсий" и пользуйтесь ими. Сложность решения *O(N)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если у вас происходит сдвиг на `A`, т.е. перестановка частей на `A`-м месте

```
   L          R
_______ _______________
```

в

```
        R           L  
 _______________ _______
```

то при этом внутренние инверсии в части `L` остаются на месте, внутренние инверсии в части `R` остаются на месте, а инверсии между частями инвертируются. Т.е. если было `K(A)` взаимных инверсий, то они исправляются, однако новое количество взаимных инверсий `Len(L)*Len(R)-K(A)`, так что изменение количества будет

```
DeltaInv = Len(L)*Len(R)-2*K(A) = A*(N-A) - 2*K(A)
```

Пример

```
[1,3,7, 0,2,4,5,6,8,9] => 
[0,2,4,5,6,8,9, 1,3,7] 
было 8 инверсий, становится 13, изменение на 5  (3*7-2*8)

[7,3,1,  0,2,4,6,8,9,5] =>
[0,2,4,6,8,9,5,  7,3,1]
было 14, становится 19, изменение на те же 5 
(поскольку количество взаимных инверсий сохранено)
```

Остаётся ;) предпосчитать количество взаимных инверсий левой и правой части исходной перестановки на каждом индексе и сохранить, тогда каждый запрос будет обработан за O(1)

Comment: За *nlogn* можно составить соответствующую таблицу. Построение инкрементальное. Можно ли за линейное время?