# Найти кол во пар за минимальное время следуя условию

Tags: python, алгоритм, перестановка

Задача состоит в том, чтобы найти количество пар, когда i < j и в то же время n[i] > n[j]. Кроме того, после подсчета первое стоящее число становится последним. Всего перестановок n - 1.

Пример:
Ввод 0 1 2 3 4

Вывод: 0 4 6 6 4
(пояснение к первому числу: сейчас пар нет)
(После первой перестановки мы получили массив 1 2 3 4 0 => у нас есть 4 пары, это 1 - 0, 2 - 0, 3 - 0, 4 - 0)
Вопрос. Как сделать это максимально эффективно? Для массива длиной 10^5. Оптимально выполняется менее чем за 2 секунды.

У меня лучшая сложность только O (n ^ 3). Из за этого длительность выполнения уходит за 20 секунд

И, пожалуйста, расскажите нам, какие алгоритмы и структуры данных вы использовали

Вот что я смог сделать

```
n = int(input())
p = list(map(int, input().split()))
sdvig = 0
def changeSdig():
    global  sdvig
    if(sdvig == len(p) - 1):
        sdvig = 0
    else:
        sdvig += 1

def findHappy():
    happy = 0
    for i in range(sdvig, len(p)):
        print(i, end=" ")
        for j in range(i, len(p)):
            print(j, end='')
            if p[i] > p[j]:
                happy += 1
        for j in range(0, sdvig - 1):
            print(j)
            if p[i] > p[j]:
                happy += 1
    #print("---------------------------------")
    for i in range(0, sdvig - 1):
        #print(i, end=" ")
        for j in range(i, sdvig - 1):
            #print(j)
            if p[i] > p[j]:
                happy += 1
    changeSdig()
    print(happy)

findHappy()
for i in range(0, len(p) - 1):
    findHappy()
```

Comment: Почитайте про число инверсий перестановки. Его надо уметь считать для исходного массива (за NlogN). При циклической перестановке число инверсий меняется вполне определённым образом (обновляется за константу), считать заново нет необходимости. Общая сложность - NlogN.

Comment: Минусующие, чем плох вопрос? ТС представил код, указал проблему. Все на месте.

Comment: Родственная задача https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1536751/

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, забыл указать, эту задачу на питоне решить невозможно на сколько я понимаю. Вот время уложится нельзя. Я на питоне писал для более простого понимания. Поправлю метку

Comment: Эта задача может быть решена на Питоне и уложится в ограничения по времени и по памяти. Не язык решает, а алгоритм.

Comment: Добавьте ссылку на проверяющую систему.

Comment: Можно на питоне уложиться. Вы по моей ссылке смотрели? Если массив инверсий построен, для каждого сдвига ответ просто по формуле получается

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy , cпасибо за ссылку и навождение! Обьязательно изучу проблему схожей задачи и число инверсий перестановки.  Если смогу решить выложу мое решение

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy к сожалению есть только текст задачи.

Comment: @MBo сейчас изучаю. Еще не до конца понял суть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Реализуем то, что я [писал в похожей теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1536754/291659)

Для подсчёта инверсий используем дерево Фенвика ([реализация взята отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23201616/844416), словарь rank используется для сжатия данных, если диапазон шире, чем 1..n), и модифицирована, чтобы по ходу дела сохранять для каждого индекса количество бОльших элементов слева, и количество меньших справа.

После первичной обработки имеем количество инверсий в исходном массиве, и указанные выше списки. Теперь для каждого циклического вращения на `А` находим количество взаимных инверсий между частями массива `K(A)` и применяем формулу из указанной темы  `DeltaInv = A*(N-A) - 2*K(A)`

На 100000 элементов тратит 0.7 секунды.

```
import random

def count_inversions(a):
    n = len(a)
    cnt = 0
    smallerright = [0]*n
    largerleft = [0]*n
    res = [0]*n
    rank = {v : i+1 for i, v in enumerate(sorted(a)) }

    counts = [0]*(n+1)
    for j in reversed(range(n)):
        tmpcnt = 0
        x = a[j]
        i = rank[x]-1
        while i:
            cnt += counts[i]
            tmpcnt += counts[i]
            i -= i & -i
        i = rank[x]
        while i <= n:
            counts[i] += 1
            i += i & -i
        smallerright[j] = tmpcnt

    counts = [0]*(n+1)
    for j in range(n):
        tmpcnt = 0
        x = a[j]
        i = rank[x]-1
        while i:
            tmpcnt += counts[i]
            i -= i & -i
        i = rank[x]
        while i <= n:
            counts[i] += 1
            i += i & -i
        largerleft[j] = j - tmpcnt

    res[0] = cnt
    k = 0
    for i in range(1, n):
        k = k  + smallerright[i-1] - largerleft[i-1]
        res[i] = cnt + i*(n-i) - 2 * k

    return res #cnt, smallerright, largerleft



def dumb(a):
    n = len(a)
    res = []
    for i in range(n):
        sh = a[i:] + a[:i]
        ic = 0
        for j in range(n-1):
            for k in range(j+1, n):
                if sh[j]>sh[k]:
                    ic += 1
        res.append(ic)
    return res


n = 6
a = list(range(1, n+1))
random.shuffle(a)

print(a)

print(count_inversions(a))

print(dumb(a))
```

Результат. Нижняя строка - контроль тупым методом.

```
[2, 5, 3, 4, 1, 6]
[6, 9, 6, 7, 6, 11]
[6, 9, 6, 7, 6, 11]
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за решение.   Я только не очень понимаю что Вы подразумеваете под инверсией) Вы имеете ввиду перестановка частей массива между собой?  те как вы писали  ---a---   -b- и  -b-   ---a---. Я правильно понял?

Comment: Инверсия - из вашего условия "когда i < j и в то же время n[i] > n[j]"